# Get path from both local and iCloud directories

Tags: sh, icloud, automator, icns, iconutil

I have an Automator Quick Action script that converts PNG to ICNS, keeping both the original file name and its original position. However, if used inside an iCloud folder or a folder with a space in its name, the script won't work.

```
#!/bin/sh

s=$1
NAME="${s%.*}"

ICONSET="$NAME.iconset"
mkdir $ICONSET

sips -z 1024 1024 $1 --out $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png
sips -z 512  512  $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_512x512.png
sips -z 512  512  $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_256x256@2x.png
sips -z 256  256  $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_256x256.png
sips -z 256  256  $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_128x128@2x.png
sips -z 128  128  $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_128x128.png
sips -z 64   64   $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_32x32@2x.png
sips -z 32   32   $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_32x32.png
sips -z 32   32   $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_16x16@2x.png
sips -z 16   16   $ICONSET/icon_512x512@2x.png --out $ICONSET/icon_16x16.png

iconutil -c icns $ICONSET

rm -rf $ICONSET
```

How do I get the current path — no matter if local or iCloud — and also make the script work in folders that contain spaces in their names?

Comment: If your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))  says `#!/bin/sh`, what you have is a `sh` script, not a Bash script. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: I've edited the tag to reflect that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more consistent with quoting in order to handle special characters like spaces in the name.

You can also write it as a for loop to prevent copy/paste errors for repetitive tasks.

Assuming `$1` is a regular file that can be read multiple times:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

s="$1"
NAME="${s%.*}"

ICONSET="$NAME.iconset"
mkdir -p "$ICONSET"

for res in 512 256 128 64 32 16; do
    x2=$((res * 2))
    sips -z $x2  $x2  "$1" --out "$ICONSET/icon_${res}x${res}@2x.png"
    sips -z $res $res "$1" --out "$ICONSET/icon_${res}x${res}.png"
done

iconutil -c icns "$ICONSET"

rm -rf "$ICONSET"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I totally overlooked quotations. Do you also have any solution to make this work when converting multiple files at once?

Comment: @Skifess you could read multiple command line arguments instead of one, or read file names from stdin one per line.